# lower bound on the norm of Hadamard product

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a nonsingular matrix, $D_1, D_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ are both diagonal matrices with decreasing positive real values on the diagonals.

Can you prove or disprove the following lower of the spectral norm (largest singular value)? 
\begin{align}
\| AD_1 - D_2 A\|_2 \geq \sigma_n(A) \cdot \sigma_n(D_1 - D_2),
\end{align}
where $\sigma_n(X)$ is the $n$-th singular value of $X$.

Equivalently, can you show 
\begin{align}
\| A \odot D\|_2 \geq \sigma_n(A) \cdot \min_i|D_{ii}|,
\end{align}
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product (entry-wise) and
\begin{align}
D = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
D_1(1,1) - D_2(1,1) & D_1(2,2) - D_2(1,1) & \cdots & D_1(n,n) - D_2(1,1) \\
D_1(1,1) - D_2(2,2) & D_1(2,2) - D_2(2,2) & \cdots & D_1(n,n) - D_2(2,2) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
D_1(1,1) - D_2(n,n) & D_1(2,2) - D_2(n,n) & \cdots & D_1(n,n) - D_2(n,n) \\
\end{array} \right]
\end{align}

Note that $D$ is singular, so classical results on lower bounds of Hadamard product do not apply here.